# Using same fragment for several tabs in Kotlin, Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm really a beginner, so please be patient.

I have a 4 tabs app, and use the same fragment for the 4 tabs. In said fragment (fragment_main.xml) I have an editText and in the main_activity.xml a FAB. The fab only displays a toast with the text in the editText. The problem is it doesn't matter in which tab I am in, it shows the text from another tab or sometimes the corresponding text, randomly.

```
        fab.setOnClickListener {view ->
        var search: EditText = findViewById(R.id.search)

        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, search.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Do I have to use a different fragment for each tab? All the tabs will be the same: a search field, a listView and the FAB which will send the data to the database and clear said tab.

I already tried to change the editText id adding the tab number to it, but it didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may helps you

1. Create four fragment class for 4 tabs.
2. I'm assuming that your first two tabs has same view. So you can reuse the same xml file for both tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way you can do this is to call the method that shows the text on the fragment from the activity, so when the fab button is clicked, it calls a fragment method to show the text. This means that as you select between tabs, the activity keeps a reference of the tab selected. Since you have only one fragment, like this one whose layout has the edit text

```
class MyOnlyFragment : Fragment() {

  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false)
    return view
  }

  fun showText() {
    Toast.makeText(context, editText.text.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
  }

  companion object {
    fun getInstance(): MyOnlyFragment = MyOnlyFragment()
  }

}
```

Now in your activity, your activity would look like this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private lateinit var fragment: MyOnlyFragment

  private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener =
    BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
      fragment = when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.navigation_home -> MyOnlyFragment.getInstance()
        R.id.navigation_dashboard -> MyOnlyFragment.getInstance()
        else -> MyOnlyFragment.getInstance()
      }
      val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
      ft.replace(R.id.frameContaienr, fragment)
      ft.commit()
      true
    }

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    fragment = MyOnlyFragment()
    val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    ft.replace(R.id.frameContaienr, fragment)
    ft.commit()
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
      fragment.showText()
    }

  }

}
```

So what fab does is to basically call the fragment's `showText` method. This example assumes you want to use only one fragment for all tabs (3 in this example but it doesn't matter) in the activity (although you can do something similar if you have other fragments with an interface)